# Heap decrease all keys in constant time

Tags: heap

I have an assignment in which I am going to implement a binary heap with all the usual operations (add,find_min,remove_min) retaining their respective running times, and with the additional operation decreaseAllKeys(int dec) running in O(1).

The easiest way would be to just loop through the heap and decrease all the keys. The structure of the heap will remain the same so this takes O(n). Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), consider including an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). and show us what you have tried.

Comment: One wonders what the utility of such a thing would be. It's clearly impossible to make changes to N things in constant time. This requirement is odd enough that I have to think that either you misunderstood the requirement, or there's something you're not telling us. Or possibly it's an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem): you have a problem and you think you need a `decreaseAllKeys` function to solve it. Please provide more information.

Comment: That said, you could get the same *effect* by applying a scaling factor to the code you use to compare keys. But again, without more context I can't imagine why you'd want to do such a thing.